# Client application for Corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am making a springboot application which will be act like a client for corda layer. 
For doing this I have to put my contracts jar and workflows jar in my client application. 
Is it safe from safety aspects or this approach is correct? 
Any another alternative without giving contracts and workflows jar.

Answer (score 0):

- When you build the `clients` module, it will fat-jar all of the dependencies (including your CorDapps) into the jar file of your SpringBoot app (i.e. webserver).
- It's safe, because if you give some party the webserver jar file and they extract your CorDapp jar files from it; they won't be able to transact with your nodes if they're not part of your network.
- And if they are part of your network, then it shouldn't be a problem that they received that jar file; because most likely they already have the CorDapps that are part of it.
- Maybe they are part of your network, but they should have only a certain sub-set of your CorDapps (i.e. they should be able to run only certain flows); then your workflows and contracts should have some validations inside of them that restrict certain actions to certain parties.
- For example, you can create a custom configuration file (see [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-create-a-cordapp-configuration-file-ef79581b9e3-ef79581b9e3c) how); and inside that file you specify the entity that can be the issuer of your tokens. Then inside your flow you fetch that value from the file and compare `getOurIdentity()` with the fetched value, if they mismtach then you throw an exception.
- Another example, you can put a list of parties as black-listed entities in a jar or zip file then upload that file to your node. Inside your flow you can add that file as an attachment to your transaction, then inside your contract, you can fetch that file and read its contents to find out if one of the participants is on the black-listed entities list or not. See example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/blacklist).